# Mouse cursor on grub

Tags: grub2, mouse

I am trying to get a cool GRUB.

Is there a way to add a mouse cursor in GRUB (to use the mouse to select options)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install an other Bootloader, if you want a gui with mouse support.

gujin has such a gui i.e.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gujin/

Comment: Does it have a config app?

Comment: Sorry - didn't see comment. And - tbh - I don't know - I just read gujin has a GUI once ^^.
For myself I don't see a reason for mouse support in my Bootloader, so I nerver did dig into it.